# Is it really clear what happened to Two-Face?

Tags: character, the-dark-knight

Did Harvey Dent, aka Two Face really die at the end of *The Dark Knight*? I thought it's canon that he becomes an enemy to Batman. I haven't seen the other Batman movies yet, so careful with spoilers...